# Trapezium from two diagonals and two non-parallel sides

Tags: geometry, nonlinear-system, geometric-construction

Is it possible to construct (and to calculate) a trapezium from it's two non-parallel sides and it's two diagonals, with other words $b,d,e,f$ are given:

[image]

I read out the equations system 
$\begin{array}{|l l}
(1) & a =c+p+q \\
(2) & h^2 =e^2 -(a-q)^2 \\
(3) & h^2 =f^2 -(a-p)^2 \\
(4) & b^2 =h^2+q^2 \\
(5) & d^2 =h^2+p^2 \\
\end{array}$ 
How can I solve that for $a,c,h,p,q$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the cosine rule
$$a^2 = b^2+e^2 -2be \cos C= d^2 +f^2 -2df \cos D\tag1
$$
and note that the triangles ADB and ACB are equal in area

$$\frac12 be \sin C =\frac12df \sin D\implies b^2e^2 (1-\cos^2 C )= d^2f^2(1-\cos^2 D)\tag2
$$
Substitute (1) into (2) to eliminate $\cos C$ and $\cos D$, yielding
$$a^2= \frac{(b^2-e^2)^2- (d^2-f^2)^2}{2(b^2+e^2 -d^2-f^2)}
$$

Similarly

$$c^2= \frac{(b^2-f^2)^2- (d^2-e^2)^2}{2(b^2+f^2 -d^2-e^2)}
$$

Depending on the given values of $b$, $d$, $e$ and $f$, the trapezium is either unique or impossible since the RHS’s of above expressions have to be positive. In the special case of $b=d$ and $e=f$, the trapezium is possible yet not unique.

Comment: A factor 2 is missed in the denominator.

Comment: @user - thanks; corrected

Answer (score 1):

It takes five dimensions ( angle or side lengths ) to construct a quadrilateral. With four dimensions quadrilaterals can be constructed only *upto a single parameter rotation* of members. There can be no unique construction.

In kinematics  the situation is referred to as a 4-Bar mechanism configuration.

Constructions for direct and crossed diagonals ( asked for in the question) are given in a rough sketch where the side/link AB is taken fixed (either end does not move) among all possibilities

Thick green two crossed diagonals cases and black direct four diagonal cases are sketched below. Possible configurations are infinitely many.

Makes no difference ... a trapezium or a quadrilateral..  diagonals direct or crossed... *the degree of freedom* is one.

EDIT1:

Even in the non-trapezium "scalene" quadrilateral of straight diagonals case the connecting rod CD passes through an instant where AB is parallel to CD. This is also true when diagonals are crossed

[image]

Comment: The solution of the problem is unique unless the diagonals and lateral sides are pairwise equal (i.e. the trapezoid is isosceles).

Comment: This is a good idea. But the fifth condition given is that the sides and diagonals lie on two parallel lines. Could you also explain how this condition affects/ does not affect the uniqueness of trapezium?

Comment: The diagonals need not to transverse on (interset) a parallel line pair Please see my last EDIT1. It is a transitory phase or   instance when connecting rod CD is instantaneously parallel to fixed side AB.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the case when the side lengths are equal and the diagonals are equal, this is impossible.

Attached are three cases with side length $AD = FD' = 4$ and diagonal length $AD' = FD = 5$:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: So a construction by compass and straightedge is not possible?

Comment: The reason it is impossible is that in this case the trapezium is not unique. However you can create some of these trapeziums with compass and straightedge.