# Construction by straightedge and compass of a trapezium from the two diagonals and the two non-parallel sides

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

[image]

Let the diagonals and the two non-parallel sides of a trapezium be given: $b,~ d,~ e,~ f$ and, as we know, $a \parallel c$ (the lengths of $a$ and $c$ are unknown).

(How to calculate the missing sides $a,~ c$ is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4094524/169241).)

*But how can I **construct** this trapezoid with a compass and ruler?*

Comment: Where are you stuck? If someone gave you $a$ and $c$, could you complete the construction? If someone gave you $p$, $q$, $r$, could you construct $\dfrac{pq}{r\sqrt{2}}$? If someone gave you $w$, $x$, $y$, $z$ could you construct $\sqrt{w^2+x^2-y^2-z^2}$?

Comment: b, d, e, f and the info a || c is given; nothing else.
PS: If a and c were also known, it would be a different (feasible) task. Unfortunately, your comment does not help me.

Comment: From $b$, $d$, $e$, $f$, construct $p:=\sqrt{b^2+d^2-e^2-f^2}$, $q:=\sqrt{b^2-d^2-e^2+f^2}$, and $r:=\sqrt{b^2-d^2+e^2-f^2}$. From *those*, construct $\dfrac{pq}{r\sqrt{2}}$; that's $a$ (according to [the answer you cited](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4094524/169241)). Then $c$ is similar.

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable. But I don't know how to construct this term p, for example.

Comment: *"I don't know how to construct this term p, for example"* ... That was the point of my first comment; to see what constructions you know how to perform. :)  Anyway ... To construct $\sqrt{w^2+x^2-y^2-z^2}$, build a right triangle w/legs $w$ & $x$, and draw a semicircle w/the hypotenuse (say, $h$) as diameter. Use the semicircle to construct a right triangle w/hypotenuse $h$, leg $y$, and other-leg $y'$. Then, use a semicircle on $y'$ to construct a rt triangle w/hypotenuse $y'$, leg $z$, and other-leg $p$. Since $p^2+y^2+z^2=h^2=w^2+x^2$, that last other-leg is the desired length. Easy-peasy!

Comment: Ok, TYVM. So I understand how to construct $p,q,r$, the three lengths of the kind $\sqrt{w^2+x^2-y^2-z^2}$. Can I ask you, what is an elegant way to construct 
$\dfrac{pq}{r\sqrt{2}}$ ? (The value $\sqrt{2}$ is clear.)

Comment: *"[W]hat is an elegant way to construct $\dfrac{pq}{r\sqrt{2}}$?"* Just set up some similar triangles. (Ignoring the $\sqrt{2}$ ...) Take any $\triangle POR$ with $p=|OP|$ and $r=|OR|$. Locate $Q$ on $\overleftrightarrow{OR}$ such that $q=|OQ|$. Construct the line through $Q$ parallel to $\overline{PR}$; let it meet $\overleftrightarrow{OP}$ at $S$, with $s:=|OS|$. Then $\dfrac{p}{r}=\dfrac{s}{q}$, so $s=pq/r$. Simple-dimple!

Comment: OK, thanks again. I think, I can make this complete. PS: I had hoped somewhere that there would be a possibility of construction without knowing the calculation results.